# what is the simplest way of testing mongodb class?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have a simple mongo class that has just two methods

```
insertDoc(): Future[Completed] ...

deleteDoc(): Future[Seq[DeleteResult]] ...
```

and I just want to have a simple test class to test those methods.

I read about embedded mongo that it might be the best way to do so but there are no really examples i can use, im using mongo-scala-driver...

can someone explain what is the best way doing so?